# Multiply vertex data with a matrix iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, opengl-es, glkit

I found a way to get the transformed vertextdata of an object they say I have to multiply the vertexdata with the matrix.But I dont know how to do it.
I have

```
GLfloat gCubeVertexData[216] = 
{
0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,          1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

etc.
};
```

and the matrix

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is an array of floats as well. Make a [GLKMatrix4](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMatrix4Make) object first.   
Then you multiply every vertex (x,y,z) from *gCubeVertexData* using one of the methods on **[Perform Mathematical Operations on Vectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011000-CH2-SW42)**